# how to disable paused subscriptions from the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

To disable users to pause their subscription, do the following:

1. Sign in to the Google Play Console.
2. Select your app, and then go to Store presence > In-app products > Subscriptions.
3. Expand the Subscription settings section.
4. Check disable Pause.

i am doing these above steps, but pause subscription is not disabled.

Comment: It might take a while for it to go into production (for instance, a day.) When did you do this?

Comment: @SAKSHI SEJWAL Have you fixed that? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I also disabled the pause option, but was still seeing it while testing monthly subscriptions in my app (yearly subscriptions never allow pause according to the docs).  I had a feeling this was because the user I was testing with is a license tester.  I reached out to google play developer support, and they confirmed that this is correct.

*"Pause and Resubscribe are both enabled for license testers even if they are disabled in the Play Console. The Resubscribe / Pause options are always on for the license tester's UI. These options will not be visible for non-tester accounts."*

This is also noted in the last paragraph of this announcement: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html

Answer (score 1):

With the new console the steps to enable/disable pause option for subscribers is actually through following steps-

1. Go to Google Play Console
2. On left side panel-> Go to monetise-> Monetisation Setup
3. There under Subscription Settings Pause can be enabled/disabled

**NOTE**- The Pause option is **not** available for free trials and annual subscriptions.

Comment: That's the correct instruction.