# Turn off pause subscription option in google play billing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I've disabled Pause subscription option in the Google Play console several days ago, but subscription still can be paused from the Google Play menu on device.

My app is in the close alpha channel. There was no production release yet. I've added myself to license testers

How can I completely disable this option, so event testers do not see the option to pause subscription?

Comment: Please share information if you already solved it. Thanks.

Comment: disabling in console doesn't disable pause for testers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69997733/4504191